# different database and codebase on each subdomain in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Let's say that I have the following domain: `www.example.test`

Now, let's say that I have the following subdomains: `sub1.example.test` and `sub2.example.test`

**First question:**

If I access `sub1.example.test`, then a codebase and database should be loaded, if I access `sub2.example.test`, then a **DIFFERENT** codebase and database should be loaded. How can I achieve this?

**Second question:**

If I access **ANY** subdomain (can be `sub1.example.test` or any subdomain), then **THE SAME** codebase should be loaded but different database. How can I achieve this?

EDIT: The app does not have to pull data from multiple databases. Let's say that each customer has its subdomain and its database

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your datbase configuration file - likely app/config/database.php - you can define more than one database connection of any type. In fact, you can define as many connections as you'd like. For instance, if your application has to pull data from 2 MySQL databases, you can define them both separately:

```
<?php
return array(

    'default' => 'mysql',

    'connections' => array(

        # Our primary database connection
        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'host1',
            'database'  => 'database1',
            'username'  => 'user1',
            'password'  => 'pass1'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        # Our secondary database connection
        'mysql2' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'host2',
            'database'  => 'database2',
            'username'  => 'user2',
            'password'  => 'pass2'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
    ),
);
```

We have our default connection still set to mysql. This means that, unless we specify otherwise, the application will use thet mysql connection.

Specify Connection
Now that we have a 2nd database connection setup - how do we use it in code?

It turns out there's a few ways!

Schema
Within the Schema Builder, you can use the Schema facade with any connection. To specify which connection to use, simply run the connection() method:

```
Schema::connection('mysql2')->create('some_table', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id'):
});
```

Query
Similar to Schema Builder, you can define a connection on the Query Builder:

```
$users = DB::connection('mysql2')->select(...);
```

Eloquent
You can also define which connection to use in your Eloquent models as well!

One way is to set the $connection variable in your model:

```
<?php

class SomeModel extends Eloquent {

    protected $connection = 'mysql2';

}
```

You can also define the connection at runtime via the setConnection method.

```
<?php

class SomeController extends BaseController {

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $someModel = new SomeModel;

        $someModel->setConnection('mysql2');

        $something = $someModel->find(1);

        return $something;
    }

}
```

Be careful about attempting to build relationships with tables across databases! It is possible to do, but it can come with some caveats and depends on what database and/or database settings you have.

Comment: hey there, thanks for the detailed answer! it provided me an idea on how to achieve it :) but what if user 1 (subdomain 1) wants one more functionality that the user 2 (subdomain 2) doesn't want? that's why I asked if there can be loaded a different codebase as well